# PHP MySQL row editor showing in wrong order

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysqli

Trying to make something so I can edit rows from database using a PHP form but when I click edit it shows in the wrong order.
I know I can't edit the top one because it's ID is 0 and i'll change that later on but the others are showing when editing they are Text, Name, Rank
But I want them to be Name, Rank, Text
You can try for yourself here:http://rumblegaming.co.uk/admin/home

```
<?php
  /*
  Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
  */

  // connect to the database
  include("connect.php");

  // creates the new/edit record form
  // since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
  function renderForm($name = '', $rank ='', $text ='', $error = '', $id = '')
  { ?>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>
  <?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?>
  </title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1><?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?></h1>
  <?php if ($error != '') {
  echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
  . "</div>";
  } ?>

  <form action="" method="post">
  <div>
  <?php if ($id != '') { ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
  <p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>
  <?php } ?>

  <strong>Name:</strong> <input type="text" name="name"
  value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/><br/>
  <strong>Rank:</strong> <input type="text" name="rank"
  value="<?php echo $rank; ?>"/><br/>
  <strong>Text:</strong> <input type="text" name="text"
  value="<?php echo $text; ?>"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>

<?php }



/*

EDIT RECORD

*/
// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
  // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    // make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
    if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
    {
      // get variables from the URL/form
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $name = htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
      $rank = htmlentities($_POST['rank'], ENT_QUOTES);
      $text = htmlentities($_POST['text'], ENT_QUOTES);

      // check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
     if ($name == '' || $rank == '')
     {
       // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
       $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
       renderForm($name, $rank, $text, $error, $id);
     }
     else
     {
       // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
       if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Team SET name = ?, rank = ?, text = ? WHERE id=?"))
       {
         $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $name, $rank, $text, $id);
         $stmt->execute();
         $stmt->close();
       }
       // show an error message if the query has an error
     else
     {
       echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
     }

     // redirect the user once the form is updated
     header("Location: home");
  }
}
// if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
else
{
  echo "Error!";
}
}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
else
{
  // make sure the 'id' value is valid
  if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
  {
    // get 'id' from URL
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    // get the recod from the database
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Team WHERE id=?"))
    {
      $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
      $stmt->execute();

      $stmt->bind_result($id, $rank, $text, $name);
      $stmt->fetch();

      // show the form
      renderForm($name, $rank, $text, NULL, $id);

      $stmt->close();
    }
    // show an error if the query has an error
    else
    {
      echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
    }
  }
   // if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php page
    else
    {
      header("Location: home");
    }
  }
}

/*

NEW RECORD

*/
// if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
else
{
  // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    // get the form data
    $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES);

    // check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
    if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '')
    {
      // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
      $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
      renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $error);
    }
    else
    {
      // insert the new record into the database
      if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT players (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)"))
      {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $lastname);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
      }
      // show an error if the query has an error
      else
      {
        echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
      }

      // redirec the user
      header("Location: view.php");
    }

    }
    // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
    else
    {
      renderForm();
    }
  }

  // close the mysqli connection
  $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Link does not work. Also, why not just use phpmyadmin or something similar?

Comment: You're using `SELECT *` in your query. If you want the fields in a specific order, have you tried `SELECT rank, text, name` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply re-arrange your select statement.

eg. instead of

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Team WHERE id=?"));
```

use

```
 if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Name, Rank, Text FROM Team WHERE id=?"));
```